# Assigning Location to Card in Simply Python Card Game

Tags: python, list, playing-cards

I'm working on a homework assignment to make a simple card game, and I don't understand why I can't use the same method to make my start deck and to assign the start location of the cards also. We're not supposed to use anything more complicated than lists and arrays (because that's all we've learned so far).

The first part (that builds the deck) works fine. The second part that's supposed to assign the location (of "deck", later I'll put in locations of "player hand" and "computer hand" to deal the cards) doesn't work and I don't get why I can't use the same method.
I keep getting the error that "list index is out of range" and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
    def startDeck():
       suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
       rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
           "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
       suitName = list(suitName)
       rankName = list(rankName)
       deck = []
       for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(13):
                card_string = rankName[rank] + " of " + suitName[suit]
                deck.append(card_string)
       return deck

    def startCardLoc():
        deck = startDeck()
        locName = ("Deck")
        deck = list(deck)
        locName = list(locName)
        cardLoc = []
        for loc in range(52):
            for firstloc in range(1):
                loc_string = locName[loc]
                cardLoc.append(loc_string)
        return cardLoc

    print startCardLoc()
```

Here's a traceback of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6d73de457be8> in <module>()
     24     return cardLoc
     25 
---> 26 print startCardLoc()

<ipython-input-1-6d73de457be8> in startCardLoc()
     20     for loc in range(52):
     21         for firstloc in range(1):
---> 22             loc_string = locName[loc]
     23             cardLoc.append(loc_string)
     24     return cardLoc

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for any and all your help.

Comment: your problem is that you're setting `locName` to `("Deck")`.  why are you doing that?

Comment: also, there's no reason to have a `for` loop when you're iterating over just one item -- as in, `range(1)`.  you don't even use the variable `firstloc`.

Comment: another thing: it's clear you mean `tuples`, not `arrays`.  i attempted to edit this, but was rejected.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. I'm really new to programming and my professor is just confusing me more than helping.

Comment: I'm trying to set the location of each of the 52 cards to "deck," and then later I'll write functions that assign the location of 5 as "player hand" and 5 to  "computer hand" and the rest will remain in the "deck". I'm not sure the best way to do this. That makes sense that I don't need a for loop.

Comment: ok, just so you know, `locName = ("Deck")` is the same as `locName = "Deck"` -- i.e., you're setting it to a string.  if you want to set it to a tuple, you need to do `locName = ("Deck",)` -- note the trailing comma.  i'm pretty sure that's what you were intending.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-examine [list()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). You call this Python built-in 4 times and it doesn't seem to be necessary in any case. In particular, `locName = list(locName)` is assigning the list `['D','e','c','k']` to `locName`, which is probably not what you intended. That line is also causing your index error, as later you try to access locName[0] through locName[51] in your for loop.

Comment: AH! Thank you! That makes sense. That is not what I intended.

Answer (score -1):

Even if it works, it would be more pythonic to write:

```
for suit in suitName:
```

I am not sure what you want to do in the second part, but  did you have a look at random.choice for example?

P.S. I am using an answer because single-line comments are not practical for not so short explanations.

Comment: Care to explain the -1?

Comment: sure.  this "answer" doesn't answer the question, as you know.  i don't buy your postscript -- this is a pretty short explanation.

Comment: Even if it works, it would be more pythonic to write:

for suit in suitName:


I am not sure what you want to do in the second part, but did you have a look at random.choice for example?

Comment: @dbliss I have posted my answer as comment. I find it a lot less readable.

Comment: you know you can format code in comments, right?  e.g., `this is code`.